# Need help matching a mattern using grep/egrep in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to match all characters of given string but those characters should match in the order as given to the bash script.

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  case $1 in
       -i)
    arg=$2
    egrep "*[$arg]*" words.txt 
    shift ;;
  esac
  shift
done

$ sh match_the_pattern.sh -i aei words.txt
```

Should return words like

```
abstentious
adventitious
sacrilegiousness
```

If you notice, first `a` is matched then `e` and then `i`, all of them are in order. Plus, the whole word is matched and filtered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
arg=$2
egrep "*[$arg]*" words.txt
```

to this:

```
arg=$(sed 's/./.*[&]/g' <<< "$2")
grep "$arg" words.txt
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: You could probably do `grep "$arg" "$3"` if the command is `sh script.sh -i aei words.txt`.

Comment: Yes, there are several other "opportunities" for improvement in the OPs script :-).

Comment: Your solution is quite good, although putting a static "words.txt" in the grep seems redundant since it appears he already includes it as an argument in his command, that's really all I was pointing out. Cheers!

Comment: I completely understand, but I'm just showing the OP how to do what she specifically asked about and keeping the changes from her script minimal so what she needs to do for that specific problem is as clear as possible rather thatn muddying it with other unrelated changes. The point in my comment is just that there are several other things that could also be improved on in her script, including the hard-coded file name.

Comment: Yep, understandable; I'm really not one of those people that expects someone answering a question to rewrite the persons entire script either, it's a nice simple solution either way (upvoted earlier).

Answer (score 3):

You may use `getopts` with some bash parameter substitution to *construct* the query string.

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts 'i:' choice
do
  case "${choice}" in
    i)
     length=${#OPTARG}
     for((count=0;count<length;count++))
     do
      if [ $count -eq 0 ]
      then 
       pattern="${pattern}.*${OPTARG:count:1}.*"
      else
       pattern="${pattern}${OPTARG:count:1}.*"
      fi
     done
    ;;    
  esac
done
# The remaining parameter should be our filename
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
filename="$1"
# Some error checking based on the parsed values
# Ideally user input should not be trusted, so a security check should
# also be done,omitting that for brevity.
if [ -z "$pattern" ] || [ -z "$filename" ]
then
 echo "-i is must. Also, filename cannot be empty"
 echo "Run the script like ./scriptname -i 'value' -- filename"
else
 grep -i "${pattern}" "$filename"
fi
```

<sub>Refer [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to know more on `parameter substitution` and [this](https://ss64.com/bash/getopts.html) for `getopts`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is matching 'a' or 'e' or 'i' because they are in a character set (`[]`).
I think the regular expression you are looking for is

```
a+.*e+.*i+.*
```

which matches 'a' one or more times, then anything, then 'e' one or more times, then anything, then 'i' one or more times.

Comment: Clearly the op need to construct such a pattern given the argument to the `-i` parameter which forms the core of the problem.